# The attribute id is undefined for the annotation type Results using Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to do this :

```
  @Select("SELECT * FROM DGE_ADJUSTMENTS WHERE COD_ADJUSTMENT = #{id}")
  @Results(id = "resultadoId", value = {
```

But The attribute id is undefined for the annotation type Results

I saw the documentation and I saw that you can do that. Any ideas?

My pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibatis-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Remove ibatis-core from the pom.xml. It's a super old [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ibatis/ibatis-core/3.0) released over ten years ago. Who told you to add that? 

Comment: Removing that dependency actually fixed it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ave fixed this.

Removing the ibatis-core dependency from pom.xml fixed the problem.